# how to add a shadow to a imageview?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimageview

i am developing a app where i am having a imageView to add a image to it by using the image property of the imageView.but before i add a image to the imageView ,i wanted to add a shadow effect on the right side of the imageView.
i found many answers in stack overflow where i was asked to call the code in drawInRect method which can be done when i draw the image on the imageView.But i am adding the image in order to give it a rich look and my images are of best quality.

Can someone suggest me a approach.

the end image i wanted looks like  [image: this]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"identifier";

    [[ListDataSource sharedDataSource] loadFiles];
    ShelfCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[[ShelfCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
            if (indexPath.row%2==0) {

                cell.imageView1.image=[[ListDataSource sharedDataSource] dataAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+0].titleImage;
                cell.imageView2.image=[[ListDataSource sharedDataSource] dataAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+1].titleImage;
                cell.imageView3.image=[[ListDataSource sharedDataSource] dataAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+2].titleImage;
                cell.imageView4.image=[[ListDataSource sharedDataSource] dataAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+3].titleImage;
                cell.imageView5.image=nil;
            }else {
                cell.rackImage.frame=CGRectMake(128, bookHeight-5, 570, 60);
                cell.imageView1.image=nil;
                cell.imageView2.image=[[ListDataSource sharedDataSource] dataAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+0].titleImage;
                cell.imageView3.image=[[ListDataSource sharedDataSource] dataAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+1].titleImage;
                cell.imageView4.image=[[ListDataSource sharedDataSource] dataAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+2].titleImage;
                cell.imageView5.image=[[ListDataSource sharedDataSource] dataAtIndex:(indexPath.row*4)+3].titleImage;
            }
    return cell;
}


**ShelfCell.m**

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {



        imageView1=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imageView1.frame=CGRectMake(10, 15, 110, 150);
        imageView1.layer.masksToBounds=NO;
        imageView1.layer.shadowRadius=5;
        imageView1.layer.shadowOpacity=0.5;
        imageView1.layer.shadowPath=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageView1.frame];
        imageView1.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
        imageView1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5,5);

        [self.contentView addSubview:imageView1];

        imageView2=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imageView2.frame=CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(imageView1.frame)+30, 15, 110, 150);

        [self.contentView addSubview:imageView2];


        imageView3=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imageView3.frame=CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(imageView2.frame)+30, 15, 110, 150);

        [self.contentView addSubview:imageView3];

        imageView4=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imageView4.frame=CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(imageView3.frame)+30, 15, 110, 150);
        [self.contentView addSubview:imageView4];


        imageView5=[[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imageView5.frame=CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(imageView4.frame)+30, 15, 110, 150);
        [self.contentView addSubview:imageView5];

    }
    return self;

}


**ListDataSource**

-(id)dataAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{

    if (index>=[arrayOfDataDirectories count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    InfoDataSource *info = [[InfoDataSource alloc] init];
    [info loadDirectoryAtPath:[arrayOfDataDirectories objectAtIndex:index]];
    [info autorelease];
    return info;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First link against the QuartzCore framework, and add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to the top of your header file.

Then assuming your `UIImageView` is called `yourImageView` (*this could be an outlet or a locally instantiated view*) you can put the following in your `viewDidLoad` method ...

```
yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
yourImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 0);
yourImageView.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
yourImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
yourImageView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:yourImageView.bounds].CGPath;
```

You shouldn't try to override the `drawRect:` method of a `UIImageView` subclass as it's never actually called. Quoted from Apple's docs ...

> Special Considerations
>
> The UIImageView class is optimized to draw its images to the display. UIImageView will not call drawRect: on a subclass. If your subclass needs custom drawing code, it is recommended you use UIView as the base class.

Comment: micpringle-  i included all the above accordingly but didn't work.do u have any other approach?

Comment: I'd need to understand more about how you've set things up, and the code you're using as I know for definite the code above works as I lifted it directly from my current project.

Comment: i am placing three images in a tableview cell and under each image i want to have shadow effect.i have taken 3 imageviews and placed them in the cell.i included your code in cell for row at index delegate method before i add the image to the imageview.

Comment: Can you please update your original question with the code where you add the `UIImageViews`

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot of how the cell looks when displayed in the tableview?

Comment: If you comment out `imageView2` through `imageView5` and set `imageView1.layer.shadowOffset` to `CGSizeMake(2,0)` are you able to see the shadow?

Comment: i got the shadow which border the imageView.now how can i get it only on the right side and to all the imageviews

Comment: `CGSizeMake(2,0)` should only show it on the right side, is this not the case?

Comment: You need to play with both the `shadowOffset` and `shadowRadius` until you get the desired effect. Since shadows are a visual element it's a little difficult to be specific since I can't see what your cell looks like, and how the shadow is being applied. If you posted a screenshot it would really help.

Comment: If you take a look at look [at this blog post](http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths) you can see the shadow is to the right and below the image. This is because it has a `shadowOffset` of `CGSizeMake(10, 10)` meaning it's offset 10 points along the X axis, and 10 points down the Y axis.

Comment: yes got it after doing modifications with the offset.tnx for clarifying few basics..upvote and accept for this

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help and glad we finally got there!

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a shadow to the layer of the image view like this

```
imageView.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(5, 5); // Choose the offset you would like
```

There are more shadow properties available. Take a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Also, in your header file you will need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`and link the QuartzCore library to your project. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: tnx for the reply but i am sorry to say that it didn't work for me.i tried changing the offset,but still didn't succeed